# Cannot install Windows 10 - error codes 0xc0000098 and 0xc00002c4

Tags: windows, windows-10, installation, windows-installation, reinstall

I'm trying to install Windows 10 on an old Thinkpad R60. Since I don't have any other installation media, I created a bootable Windows 10 USB stick following this [tutorial](https://wycd.net/posts/2015-03-10-creating-a-bootable-windows-10-usb-drive-on-linux.html). The tutorial works and I was able to install Windows 10 this way in the past. The system was set up for dual boot Windows 10 + Linux Mint Debian Edition 4, but after finishing a lengthy and involved installation process, I was only able to boot into LMDE from the GRUB menu. When selecting Windows 10, the screen just turned black for a moment and returned to the GRUB menu, which is why now I'm reinstalling Windows 10 only.

To do this, I started Tails from another USB stick and used `disks` to format the HDD to NTFS. One bad sector was displayed, but the HDD used to work fine. Afterwards, I rebooted and plugged in the Windows 10 installation stick. The Windows logo appears, but the installation process interrupts with the following bluescreen:

> Recovery
>
> Your PC/Device needs to be repaired
>
> An unexpected error has occurred.
>
> Error code: 0xc0000098
>
> You'll need to use recovery tools. If you don't have any installation media (like a disc or USB device), contact your PC administrator or PC/Device manufacturer.
>
> Press Enter to try again
>
> Press F8 for Startup Settings

When I press Enter, the screen blacks out for a moment and returns to the bluescreen. When I press F8, the screen blacks out for a moment and returns to a similar bluescreen, but with error code 0xc00002c4.

What could be the problem? Is it possible that a single bad sector is triggering this error?

I *urgently* need this system to be set up for work, as I currently do not have any alternatives. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I have the launch date of this machine in 2015. It probably is not certified to run Windows 10. When I look for Lenovo Windows 10 drivers, the R80 does not even come up.

Comment: Actually, it runs just fine and it's not even slow... But I couldn't get it to work for dual boot with Linux, and now I can't install it standalone. But yes, the machine is not the newest (typo: it's an R60, not R80), but tough as a bone

Comment: I would expect that after repartitioning it with gnome-disks, the installation should run without any problems. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I am not sure about dual boot - that is a concept I left behind many years ago. I use VMware to run multiple operating systems.